# Calling A Method With A Delegate in Objective-C (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, delegates

I tried to replicade a couple of posts here on stackoverflow, for passing data and make calls with 2 view controllers, but without success.

So I have my **ViewController (1st)** and **EditableViewController (2nd)**

When I'm in my **EditableViewController (2nd)**, I click a Button that triggers an IBAction with the method **SendTextToViewController**.
After that, I was expecting for the method **didReceiveMessage**, in my **ViewController (1st)** to run, and show me "BANANAS" with NSLog.

Ultimately, **I want to send data from my second Controller, to the First Controller**.

I'm having a hard time understanding this delegates thing. And I have read a dozen tutorials, videos e documentation trying to figure this out. I think I'm almost there, but can't seem to figure why this is not working.

Can anyone help me please? The code is bellow.

Thank you!

**// ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didReceiveMessage:(NSString *)string;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ViewControllerDelegate>;

@end
```

**// ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

-(void)didReceiveMessage:(NSString *)string{
  NSLog(@"BANANAS");
}

@end
```

**// EditableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ViewControllerDelegate;

@interface EditableViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *SendTextToViewController;

- (IBAction)SendTextToViewController:(id)sender;

@end
```

**// EditableViewController.m**

```
#import "EditableViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation EditableViewController

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize TextField;
@synthesize SendTextToViewController;


- (IBAction)SendTextToViewController:(id)sender {
               [delegate didReceiveMessage:TextField.text];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
          [self setTextField:nil];
          [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

Comment: Try loggging `delegate` in `(IBAction)SendTextToViewController:(id)sender` to check if your delegate is still there, it might get deallocated

Comment: You don't show anything in your code that sets the delegate variable to point to your view controller.  Do you do that?

Comment: See Robert Vojta's answer. He's right, you did the opposite from what you should. Long story short, what you should do is populate your EditableViewController from your ViewController (1st) (navigation for example), and make your ViewController (1st) a delegate of your EditableViewController. And then when you click a button in EditableViewController, it sends a message to ViewController (1st) for the proper method call. I can provide more details if you need.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you for everyones help. I was indeeed doing it the wrong way. And Phillip was right also. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did it in opposite way ... Do this ...

- create EditableViewControllerDelegate,
- your ViewController should conform to EditableViewControllerDelegate protocol,
- assign your ViewController instance as a delegate of EditableViewController instance

Comment: This is the correct answer.  In addition, make sure for step two that you conform to the protocol in the @interface line like this <EditableViewControllerDelegate> or whatever name you assign it.  You are conforming incorrectly in your post above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! That finally worked. I think I'm sarting to get how it works now =)